# In ES6 promise, are "then" handlers called synchronously if they don't return new promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

If I have the following code in ES6, where "then" handlers don't return new promise, will both "then" handlers be called synchronously or each new "then" handler is called asynchronously one after another?

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {console.log(1)})
  .then(() => {console.log(2)})
```

Comment: There is good [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) on this if you scroll down to the section titled "Chaining" where it states: When a value is simply returned from within a then handler, it will effectively return `Promise.resolve(<value returned by whichever handler was called>)`

Comment: Thank you, so the simple answer is: **"then" handlers are called asynchronously.**